# Splitting of poisson and expected value

Tags: probability-theory

Rainfall times at a certain location occur according to a Poisson process with rate $\lambda>0$. Each time it rains, the amount of rani that falls has a Uniform distribution on $[0,b]$ independently of times and amounts of all other rainfall. Let $R(t)$ be the total amount of rainfall up to time $t$. For $0<a<b$, let $N_a(t)$ be the number of times it rains more than amount $a$ before time $t$.
Find the distribution of $N_a(t)$ and hence calculate $\mathbb{E}(R(t)|N_a(t) = n).$

I found the distribution of $N_a(t)$ (by summing binomial r.v.s) to get
$$N_a(t) \sim \mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda t\times (1-\frac{a}{b}))
$$
however, I'm stuck in attempting the second part.
I think $R(t) = \sum_{i=1}^{N(t)} X_i$, where $X_i$ is rainfall amount at occurrence $i$ and $N(t)\sim\mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda t)$ is the poisson process of rain times.

Following from @Math1000's hint:
$$\mathbb{E}(R(t)|N_a(t) = n) = \sum_{m=n}^\infty \mathbb{E}(R(t)|N_a(t) = n, N(t) = m)\mathbb{P}(N(t) = m)$$
First, consider $R(t) | N_a(t) = n, N(t) = m)$. This can be decomposed into the two sums
$$R(t)|(N_a(t) = n, N(t) = m) = \sum_{i=1}^n J_i (J_i > a) + \sum_{i=n+1}^m J_i ( J_i < a)
$$
where it can be shown that $J_i ( J_i > a) \sim \mathrm{Unif}(a,b)$ and $J_i ( J_i < a) \sim \mathrm{Unif}(0,a)$.
Hence, the expected value of the LHS is expected value of $n$ iid $\mathrm{Unif}(0,a)$ r.v.s $+$ the expected value of sum of $m-n$ iid $\mathrm{Unif}(0,a)$ r.v.s
Thus,
$$\mathbb{E}(R(t)|N_a(t) = n, N(t) = m) = \frac{n(a+b)}{2} + \frac{(m-n)a}{2} = \frac{nb+ma}{2}.$$
Hence, we have
$$\mathbb{E}(R(t)|N_a(t) = n) = \sum_{m=n}^\infty (\frac{nb+ma}{2})\times \frac{e^{-\lambda t}(\lambda t)^m}{m!}$$
and it seems like it's hard to simplify this...

Comment: Condition on $N(t)$: $$
\mathbb E[R(t)\mid N_a(t)=n] = \sum_{m=n}^\infty \mathbb E[R(t)\mid N_a(t)=n, N(t)=m]\mathbb P(N(t)=m),
$$
then consider that conditioned on $\{N_a(t)=n,N(t)=m\}$, this is a sum of $n$ $\mathcal U(0,b)$ random variables $J_k$ conditioned on $\{J_k>a\}$ and $m-n$ $\mathcal U(0,b)$ random variables $J_k$ conditioned on $\{J_k<a\}$.

Comment: I got a sum that I couldn't simplify:  
$$\frac{nb}{2}\sum_{m=n}^\infty \frac{e^{-\lambda t}(\lambda t)^m}{m!} + \frac{a}{2}\sum_{m=n}^\infty \frac{me^{-\lambda t}(\lambda t)^m}{m!}$$.  
Not sure if I correctly followed your hint. I'l post what I did in the OP